# Generic Constraints C#

Tags: c#, generics

I need to make some of my `classes` `inherit` from `Interface` with `generic field`
like that

```
public Interface ICommon<Ttype>
{
  Ttype Filed{get;set;}
}

public Class class1:Icommon<int>
{
  int Filed{get;set;}
}

public Class class2:Icommon<double>
{
  double Filed{get;set;}
}
```

I created a `generic class with constraints` that uses classes `class1` and `class2` to make some operations like that:

```
public Class GenericClass<Ttype,Tcommon> where Ttype:ICommon<Tcommon>
{
    //forexample
    public Ttype someOperation(Ttype x)
    {
    var a=x.Field;
    //.............
    }
}
```

every time I use the `GenericClass` I have to know the `type of Field` of the class I used say `class1` or `class2` to be able to pass it to match the `generic constraint`

Is there a way to write `GenericClass` like that:

```
public Class GenericClass<Ttype,Tcommon> where Ttype:**ICommon**
{
  //forexample
  public Ttype someOperation(Ttype x)
  {
    var a=x.Field;
    //.............
  }
}
```

by writting `ICommon` without `<TCommon>` ??

**Update:**
or how to edit `ICommon` `interface` to be like that

```
 public Interface ICommon
    {
      Ttype Filed{get;set;}
    }
```

Comment: How would you expect the compiler to infer `TCommon` if you don't specify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood what you intended to do:

```
public interface ICommon<T>
{
    T Field { get; set; }
}

public class GenericClass<T>
{
    public ICommon<T> SomeOperation(ICommon<T> x)
    {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to use generic constraints 
public Class GenericClass<Ttype,Tcommon> where Ttype:ICommon<Tcommon>

Comment: So why not use GenericClass<T> and inside the class add the ICommon logic?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: no.

You need to tell the compiler type of generic argument.
In fact, `GenericClass<int>` and `GenericClass<string>` are two different classes in CLR.